# Insert array in to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert an array in to MySQL using PHP.  I followed the excellent advice given on here to use the implode command and it worked great for one array, but this one seems to be dying.  This array is slightly different than the other, but I don't know how to explain the difference.

Here is my code:

```
    $sql = array(); 
foreach( $ride_detail as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '('.$row['id'].', "'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['name']).'",
  "'.$row['version'].'")';
}
mysql_query('INSERT IGNORE INTO ride (ride_id, name, version) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

I'm getting this message over and over again.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in ride_details.php on line 60

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in ride_details.php on line 60

Warning: Illegal string offset 'version' in ride_details.php on line 61
```

The content of my array (using print_r) is:

> Array ( [id] => 21570117 [name] => Night ride home from work [start_date_local] => 1347302039 [elapsed_time] => 53:56 [moving_time] => 52:04 [distance] => 12.6 >>[average_speed] => 14.5 [elevation_gain] => 474 [location] => Englewood, CO [start_latlng] => Array ( [0] => 39.547792011872 [1] => -104.86300536431 ) [end_latlng] => Array ( [0] => 39.655485888943 [1] => -104.88656991161 ) [version] => 1355428869 [athlete] => Array ( >>[id] => 832001 [name] => Bob Kratchet [username] => bob_kratchet ) [bike] => Array ( [id] => 281303 [name] => Giant Allegre commuter ) [maximum_speed] => 29.3 [calories] => 372 >[average_power] => 107 [commute] => 1 )

I am a complete noob...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: is that print_r($row) or print_r($ride_detail) ??

Comment: One other piece of advice - if you are _ever_ going to want to use the information in the call in a query, have multiple rows in a different table - storing more than a single piece of data in any field is going to bite you in the backside sooner or later. You should read up on [data normalisation](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Comment: That's print_r($ride_detail).  My plan is to have each piece of the array in a separate column, each separated out by rows.  I didn't put my whole example here because the dataset was too huge.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `$ride_detail` is just one array, `$row` is `21570117` (integer), `Night ride home from work` (string), and so on, one by one. The code then attempts to get the `id` key of each element, then the `name` key, and so on, generating a *[expletive]*-ton of error messages as it goes.

It looks like you're intending to have `$ride_detail` be an array of arrays, or you don't actually want a `foreach` loop at all.

Comment: Yes, correct.  There are 23 values, but for my proof of concept I was only wanting to import 3 of the values in to a row.  If I prepare the row do I have to import every value?  How do I get around it trying to get an id for each element, because it's still an array right?  I'm a complete noob.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   foreach( $ride_detail as $row ) {
     $sql = array( $row['id'], mysql_real_escape_string($row['name']), $row['version'])  ;

         }
  mysql_query('INSERT IGNORE INTO ride (ride_id, name, version) VALUES  ($sql[0] ,$sql[1] , $sql[2] ) ');
```

Comment: Thank you, I was just reading last night that I shouldn't use mysql_ anymore.  Unfortunately I was learning through w3schools and tizag where that is the method used.  I will try to switch to PDO, do you have an example for that?